# Publish APK on Store - Ionic V5/Capacitor/Angular - Permission Problem

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, ionic-native, capacitor

I’m trying to publish my first APK on the google store, and are requesting
android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, but i don’t use camera or audio plugins. Just use the location, how do I solve it?

Ionic V5 with Capacitor and Angular

my package json:

```
    {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-mask": "8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the permission that you don’t need from the AndroidManifest.xml.
Capacitor adds all the permissions the plugins need, but you can remove the ones your app doesn’t use.